# How to disable auto sort on sigma grid?

Tags: jquery, sigma-grid-control

i want to disable the autosort feature of sigmagrid, because the order was set from database.

in my case, the order when the grid loaded is by alphabet ascending.

in my database con for load grid, i've set the order by on select query, why do the grid still loaded by alphabet order?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `remoteSort` property to **true**. See the API: http://www.sigmawidgets.com/products/sigma_grid2/docs/sigma_grid.html#config_remotesort